# Checking for overlapping appointments in database not working?

Tags: java, sql

I'm saving appointments to a database and have a method that checks if times are overlapping.

```
public static boolean checkForOverlappingAppointment(Timestamp start, Timestamp end, int 
customerID) {    
try {        
String sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE Customer_ID = ?";        
PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(customerID));
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();       
while (rs.next()) { 
    Timestamp startOtherAppts = rs.getTimestamp("Start");
    Timestamp endOtherAppts = rs.getTimestamp("End");   
     if ((start.before(startOtherAppts) && end.after(endOtherAppts)) ||                    
     (start.before(startOtherAppts) && end.after(startOtherAppts) && 
     end.before(endOtherAppts)) || (start.after(startOtherAppts) && 
     start.before(endOtherAppts) && end.after(endOtherAppts)) ||                    
     (start.after(startOtherAppts) && end.before(endOtherAppts))) 
     {    
     return true;
        }
    }
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    }
   return false;
}
```

I'm calling the method using

```
if (DBAppointments.checkForOverlappingAppointment(Timestamp.valueOf(startDateTimeZDT.toLocalDateTime()), Timestamp.valueOf(endDateTimeZDT.toLocalDateTime()), customerIDint)) {
Alert alert3 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert3.setHeaderText("APPOINTMENT OVERLAP");
alert3.setContentText("Appointment overlaps with an existing appointment.");    
alert3.showAndWait();}
```

I don't receive any errors when saving appointments although they can be for the same exact times.
I'm converting a `LocalTime` to a `ZonedDateTime` to save in the DB by using `Timestamp.valueOf(startDateTimeZDT.toLocalDateTime()` `Timestamp.valueOf(endDateTimeZDT.toLocalDateTime()`

I can't seem to find out where it is going wrong at.  Any help would be great!

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. No need to use `Timestamp` class at all.

Comment: Is this helpful? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap). I too recommend that you don’t use `Timestamp`. It’s poorly designed, a true hack on top of the already poorly designed ’Date` class, and long outdated.

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't know they were outdated lol.  I'm just a student trying to follow a rubric.  I've moved over to ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTimes as I try to figure out the project.  The information below has helped nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Why they were outdated? [Official answer here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database may do that work for you.

```
public static boolean checkForOverlappingAppointment(
        LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, int customerID) {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT *"
                + " FROM appointments"
                + " WHERE Customer_ID = ? and Start < ? and end > ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, customerID);
        ps.setObject(2, end);
        ps.setObject(3, start);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // If there is a result row, we know it’s an overlapping appointment
        return rs.next();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**java.time:** I recommend that you use java.time for your dates and times. Assuming that your start and end columns have type `datetime` or `timestamp` (without time zone), `LocalDateTime` is the correct corresponding type to use in Java. Since JDBC 4.2 you can directly pass `LocalDateTime` and other java.time classes to your prepared statement using its `setObject` method.

**Checking for overlap:** Your logic was overly complicated for this check. The argument may be a bit tricky, but as you can see, my code is simple. For each appointment already in the database there are three possibilities: either it’s earlier, it’s overlapping or it’s later. If its start is before the end of this appointment we know it’s not later. If its end is after the start of this appointment, it cannot be earlier. If both conditions are fulfilled, it must be overlapping.

**Was there an error in your logic?** First of all I found your `if`  condition unreadable. My code formatter formatted it in this way, which helps quite a bit:

```
        if ((start.before(startOtherAppts) && end.after(endOtherAppts))
                || (start.before(startOtherAppts)
                        && end.after(startOtherAppts)
                        && end.before(endOtherAppts))
                || (start.after(startOtherAppts)
                        && start.before(endOtherAppts)
                        && end.after(endOtherAppts))
                || (start.after(startOtherAppts) && end.before(endOtherAppts))) {
            return true;
        }
```

I think you are not taking the cases into account where either both appointments have the exact same start time or they both have the same end time. You are always only checking whether one time is strictly before or strictly after the other.

**Error handling:** I don’t think you will want just to return `false` in case of an SQL error.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

## Tricky business

Handling appointments is actually complicated business.

I will assume your appointments are like dentist or car mechanic where you intend to keep the time-of-day the same, adjusting the moment as needed to abide by politically-created anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). This would be in contrast to events that are driven by natural time, such as a rocket launch.

To store such appointments, you need *three* columns in your database:

- Intended time zone. If your database lacks a data type for this, use a textual column to store [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/New_York` or `Africa/Casablanca`.
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, to store the date and time-of-day of the appointment but without the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).
- A duration, for how long the appointment will last. If your database lacks a data type for this, store text in standard [ISO 8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. For example, one and a half hours would be `PT1H30M`.

### Time zones change

We cannot store a moment, a specific point on the timeline, for appointments because we never know when politicians will change the offset used for the time zone(s) in their jurisdiction. Politicians around the world have shown a predilection for changing their time zone rules. They do so surprisingly often, and with little or even no warning. So we programmers must always assume future changes to our time zone rules.

When determining a schedule, such as your desired query, we must dynamically determine a moment for each appointment. We must craft the query to convert each appointment row’s stored values into a a dynamically calculated moment.

- For the start of the appointment, we take the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` value, apply the row's time zone, to get a moment, a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value.
- For the end of the appointment, we take that generated `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value and add to it the row’s duration value.

### SQL

You may be able to craft such a query if your database offers robust date-time handling facilities.

### Java

If your database lacks robust date-time handling facilities, then bring the data into Java to be processed and filtered.

Define a class to represent each row. Here we use a [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```java
record Appointment ( UUID uuid , ZoneId zoneId , LocalDateTime start , Duration duration ) {}
```

Retrieve the data, and collect.

```java
List< Appointment > appointments = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
UUID uuid = myResultSet.getObject( … , UUID.class ) ;
ZoneID zoneId = ZoneId.of( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
LocalDateTime start = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
Duration duration = Duration.parse( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
appointments.add( new Appointment( uuid , zoneId , start , duration ) ) ;
```

Define the target start and end of your search. Generally best to use Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This provides for neatly abutting spans, and other benefits.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = zdtStart.plusHours( 2 ) ;
```

Adjust those to UTC (an offset of zero hour-minutes-seconds) by extracting an `Instant`.

```java
Instant targetStart = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant targetEnd = zdtEnd.toInstant() ;
```

You could code the logic yourself for asking if an appointment overlaps the target span-of-time. But I find it easier to use the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

```java
Interval target = Interval.of( targetStart , targetEnd ) ;
```

Now we can loop our list of `Appointment` objects, to compare each against our target.

```java
List< Appointment > hits = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( Appointment appointment : appointments ) 
{
    ZonedDateTime start = appointment.start().atZone( appointment.zoneId() ) ;
    ZonedDateTime stop = start.plus( appointment.duration() ) ;
    Interval appointmentInterval = Interval.of( start , stop ) ;
    if( appointmentInterval.overlaps( target ) )
    {
        hits.add( appointment ) ;
    }
}
return List.copyOf( hits ) ;  // Return an unmodifiable list, as a generally good habit.
```

Reminder: Your host operating system, database engine, and Java implementation likely each have their own copy of the time zone rules ([*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), usually). Be sure to update all of them if the rules for any time zones you care about are being changed.

### Avoid legacy date time classes

Never use the terrible date-time classes such as `Timestamp`, `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. These are frightfully flawed, designed by people who did not understand the subtleties and complexities of date-time handling.

These legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later requires [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to support the *java.time* types.